# Converting a large XML file to Excel

Tags: xml, xlsx, file-conversion, opendata

I want to convert the following XML file (**WARNING: it's 40MB**), http://www.rvo.nl/sites/default/files/open_data/dop_projecten.xml, to a more readable format. Any hints on how to do this?

I have been trying to convert it to Excel, but it keeps crashing. My primary goal is to be able to sort the different projects in the file on the basis of `year` or `Allterms`.

Comment: more readable by what, a human, or a computer program?  Note that Excel is an XML format, that's what the x means at the end of xls.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion with Excel works for me.

[image]

The structure of this XML is very simple, but it's a pretty big file (39 Mb), so it'll take a few minutes. Perhaps your computer lacks memory. [Here is the file in CSV format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jtmtt7yeijw9yix/xml.csv?dl=0) if it can help.

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways would be to use [Online XML to Excel Converter](https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-excel), for example, provided by Conversion Tools - https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-excel.

You upload the XML file and in a minute download the Excel file which has a table structure.

So the structured data from the XML file will be transformed into the table format.

For [Converting XML to CSV](https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-csv) - use the following page https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-csv.